# 2 dictionaries that need to calculate with their value's

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, extract

in the code below i have 2 dictionaries. The first dictionary is a list of letters that my program is giving the user (im making scrabble)

so my program gives the user a list with seven random letters:

```
display_hand({'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1})
```

the value of the keys in the dictionary means how much times you have that letter, so in this example you have 2 times the letter l.

But now i create a new dictionary by asking the user to make a word out of these letters: I do this with the following code:

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d


h = histogram(raw_input("what word do you make out of these letters?"))
print h
```

So if i choose the make the word aim the outcome of that function will be:

```
{'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1}
```

but i just dont know how to extract this dictionary from the display_hand dictionary.

because the display_hand dictionary should now change in one of the 2 dictionaries below:

```
display_hand({'q':1, 'l':2, 'u':1})
display_hand({'a':0, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':0, 'u':1, 'i':0})
```

This is because i have used my letters: A, I and M

It would be very great if someone could help me with this problem, anyway already thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will give output as `{'a':0, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':0, 'u':1, 'i':0}` if input word is *aim*

```
import collections

d = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}

inp_list = list(raw_input())

user_h = collections.Counter(inp_list)

for key in user_h:
    if key in d:
        d[key] = d[key] - user_h[key]

print d
```

**inp_list** is the list of characters in the input string, **user_h** is the dictionary of the input word. Then you can iterate over the dictionaries for the required output. You can also put a check if the value of a key goes negative (which should be prevented).

Hope it helps!